# Partially sticky footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky-footer

I've been trying to create a partially sticky footer. I've managed to make it work "almost" as intended. But I think I might have over complicated the issue and I'm having issues knowing what's going wrong.

My footer is broken into 2 parts. Part1 is always visible as a sticky footer, part2 only shows up when you scroll to the bottom of the document, or if you toggle it's visibility.

At the moment it is doing just that, but a little more.

How I'm making things happen is:

- On the scroll event I'm removing the `display:fixed` from the footer and the padding of the main div.
- On the click event I'm animating the `bottom:value` to toggle the footer.

The problems arise when the triggers overlap. So if you scroll to the bottom, part2 shows up, but you can still toggle the footer. When you scroll back up you'll see a jitter where all the css is trying to get back into place.

Basically, if you scroll up and down, it's all good (except a little space between footer and content, not too worried though). And if you're not at the bottom of the page and toggle the footer, all is good as well.

- How would you guys go about destroying that jitter?
- Any ideas on how to do the same with less code also appreciated, but not the main problem, I think xD

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="innerContent">
        <!-- ADD CONTENT HERE OR SET THE HEIGHT -->
    </div>
    <div class="footerContainer">
        <div class="footerShow"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#ccc;
}
.innerContent {
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.footerContainer {
    width:600px;
    position:fixed;
    background:blue;
}
.showFooterContainer {
    position:inherit;
    bottom:none;
}
.footerShow {
    width:600px;
    height:50px;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}
.footer {
    width:600px;
    height:250px;
    background:orange;
}
```

**jQUERY**

```
  $('.content').css('padding-bottom', ($('.footerContainer').height() + 'px'));
  $('.footerContainer').css('bottom', ('-' + $('.footer').height() + 'px'));

  $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scrollH = $(window).scrollTop(),
          windowH = $(window).height(),
          documentH = $(document).height(),
          footerH = $('.footer').height(),
          footCont = $('.footerContainer'),
          footContH = footCont.height(),
          footShowH = $('.footerShow').height(),
          desiredH = footShowH - footContH + 'px';

    if (footCont.css('bottom') == '0px') {
      footCont.animate({
        bottom: desiredH},
        600
      );
    }
    if ( scrollH < (documentH - windowH - footerH) ) {
        footCont.removeClass('showFooterContainer');
        $('.content').css('padding-bottom', footContH + 'px');
    } else {
        footCont.addClass('showFooterContainer');
        $('.content').css('padding-bottom', '0px');
    }
  });

  $('.footerShow').click(function(){
    var footCont = $('.footerContainer'),
        footContH = footCont.height(),
        footShowH = $('.footerShow').height(),
        desiredH = footShowH - footContH + 'px';

    if (footCont.css('bottom') == desiredH) {
      footCont.animate({
        bottom:0},
        1200
      );
    }
    if (footCont.css('bottom') == '0px') {
      footCont.animate({
        bottom: desiredH},
        1200
      );
    }
  });
```

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/kutus/2/edit?html,css,js,output)**

PS - I know I shouldn't declare variables all over the place, but I'm still struggling with scope.

Comment: You are meaning when you scroll to the bottom, click the yellow part, then scroll back up - it jumps, correct?

Comment: @ZachSaucier Exactly, can't quite wrap my head around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like use a boolean variable to keep track of the state it is in, disabling the click event if the page is scrolled to the bottom section. You could also do this by using the variables change, but this way is simple, just requiring and added `if` statement and toggling a boolean

```
var isAtBottom = false; // At top
...
    if (scrollH < (documentH - windowH - footerH)) {
        isAtBottom = true;
        ...
    else {
        isAtBottom = false;
        ...
...
$('.footerShow').click(function () {
    if (!isAtBottom) {
       ... Your code ...
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/rebehofu/1/edit)

Comment: Perfect sense. While you're at it, any idea why `.innerContent` separates from `.footerContainer` when I scroll to the bottom? I'm not using margins, which I believe could cause that behaviour. The darker gray is `.content` showing in the middle.

Comment: @FernandoSilva The space in between the body and the footer when you scroll down is due to the last paragraph's (default) `margin-bottom`. You can remove this by using `p:last-of-type { margin-bottom:0; }`, [like this demo does](http://jsbin.com/rebehofu/3/edit). You can easily find the sources of problems like this using inspect element (Chrome's is great for it) and check the margins for related and nearby elements

Comment: I kept playing around and adding other tricks to this. Thought I might as well share it. Now it's a partially sticky footer with an under the rug sub footer xD http://jsbin.com/cexap/2/edit